# Visible variables in c++ and how to make variable visible more

Tags: c++, variables

I am still a beginner in c++, but I know something. I am studying the 1st term and I wanna make my own project, IMO it's the best way to learn to program. Anyway
 I wanna load data from file to dynamic array (and I know how to do that) but I to that job be done by special function and to that array be visible for other function (alternativity global). I know that using global variables is not good idea so I am thinking if it's possible to make variable friend with NO classes (bc I didn't use and learn classes yet)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: your question is not quite clear, but it sounds as if you should pass the variable as parameter to the function. No need for friends or global variables

Comment: You can pass the array as an argument? Or return the array from the function?

Comment: "dynamic array" - you mean `std::vector`  right?

Comment: dynamic array, i meant pointers `int* name = new int [n];`

Comment: @some-programmer-dude, I am a beginner so maybe you right. I'd to fun `_loadFile()` make a dynamic array and save their data. How to return it, if that fun will make dyn. array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`friend` is not what you're looking for. A variable is just a named object. What you want to do here is not to somehow access the function's variable from the outside (that's not actually possible, function variables only exist when the function is executing). You want to *transfer* the object from one function to th other. That's done through the function's *return value*:

```
std::vector<int> readDataFromFile() {
    std::vector<int> data;

    // Read the file and store it into `data`

    return data;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> myData = readDataFromFile();

    // Use `myData` as needed
}
```

You can see above that `readDataFromFile` works on its `data` variable, then returns it. This means that, right as `readDataFromFile` ends, `myData` in main (another, independent object) is initialized from `data`, and the data itself lives on.

Notes:

- Do *not* use C-style arrays, `new` or `delete`. These are meant for compatibility with C and low-level memory management, not general use. A C++ dynamic array is an `std::vector<YourType>`.

Further notions:

- Here `myData` is *move-initialized*, which means that no copy of the data is made: the dynamic array is transferred directly from `data` to `myData`
- This is a case where NRVO can occur. That's an optimization which notices that `data` is redundant, and will replace it with direct access to `myData`, so there will only ever be one vector object throughout the program's execution. This is not observable in the general case., wo you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It resolved my problem at all :)